# How to get system configuration information without dmidecode

Tags: linux, bios, dmidecode

In order to collect some system configuration information, I have been using `dmidecode` and the related tool `lshw` to find the information.  This works great on most machines, but I have recently got access to a server to test my scripts on.  `dmidecode` gives me the error:

```
# No SMBIOS nor DMI entry point found, sorry.
```

and `lshw` doesn't work as well.  If there is a way to fix this, I would appreciate the help.  Otherwise, I need to collect the following information without using `dmidecode`:

- System manufacturer
- System model number
- System serial number
- The BIOS date

Comment: What's the hardware on this server?

Comment: What distro and are you trying to run these commands as root or via sudo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the reason `dmidecode` and `lshw` don't work is because the machines I was testing them on were virtual machines, apparently.  It seems that virtual machines don't normally have the required information for `dmidecode` and `lshw` to work, so I don't have to fill in these fields for virtual machines.

Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: Virtual machines do, as hardware is emulated. VZ containers do not.

Comment: These VMs, run on a Xen hypervisor, appear to not have the required information or configuration to access SMBIOS or DMI information.  I'm not sure if that has to do with a VM emulating hardware or not.  I'm also not sure what a VZ container is.

Comment: Also if you are running custom Linux version, Ex :Buildroot based you wouldn't get the expected output.